# Export RSA public key into byte array

Tags: c#, rsa

I create public and private key for RSA algorithm. I would like to export public key into byte[]. I did method called FunctionA bellow, later i got suggestion to use the ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo which is included in FunctionB bellow.
 **I have to store the public key in byte[] and sent it into server which isn't in .NET.
I'd like to know if some of these approaches are correct or i should consider some other solution.**

```
private RSAParameters RSAParamsPublicKey;
private RSAParameters RSAParamsPrivateKey;
private byte[] keyPublicKeyArray;

private void FunctionA() {
var csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
RSAParamsPrivateKey = csp.ExportParameters(true);
RSAParamsPublicKey = csp.ExportParameters(false);
List < byte > keyPublicKeyList = new List < byte > ();
foreach(byte b in RSAParamsPublicKey.Exponent) {
    keyPublicKeyList.Add(b);
}
foreach(byte b in RSAParamsPublicKey.Modulus) {
    keyPublicKeyList.Add(b);
}
keyPublicKeyArray = keyPublicKeyList.ToArray();
}

private void FunctionB() {
var csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
csp.ExportParameters(true);
csp.ExportParameters(false);
keyPublicKeyArray = csp.ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo();
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show any importing of any keys at all. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the problem you're having.

Comment: I meant export, my bad. Its all about export, not import. In both cases im exporting Public Key into byte array keyPublicArray

Comment: They are different because they are completely different formats. Function B is the one you want because it is easy to restore the public key (just use `ImportSubjectKeyInfo()`), standards-based, and broadly supported across other platforms and languages. Function A is little more than the internal representation of the data, and without much effort can only be used to re-create the public key on another .Net platform.

Comment: I have to store the public key and send it as a byte[] into server via HTTP POST, server isn't in .NET, so should i use one of those approaches or something different

Comment: Those are details that should have been in the question. On stackoverflow you need to include all the relevant details in your question. The format is not designed for a series of questions and answer but rather a single question with multiple answers.